# How to call Java string in React Native and display it in real time

Tags: java, string, react-native

I created string in java:

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public int measureConcentration(double[] means){
        return (int) ((means[3] / means[1]) * 100) ;
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int score = measureConcentration(bandMeans);
        String ratio = Integer.toString(score);
        // Print values
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(ratio));
```

I would like to display it in react native. But when I try to compile app in powershell I receive an error due to `cannot find symbol int score = measureConcentration(bandMeans);`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have main inside function getRatio?

Comment: I tried without this line with getRatio. Crashed with the same error

Comment: So please remove that line from your code and also post the full error you getting

Comment: error: cannot find symbol
        int score = measureConcentration(bandMeans);

Comment: Where did you define the function `measureConcentration`? Can you share it in the question code as well?

Comment: public int measureConcentration(double[] means){
        return (int) ((means[3] / means[1]) * 100) ;
    }

It hets values 3 and 1 from:

    public BandPowerExtractor(double[] freqList) {

        f = freqList;

        // Define band power indices
        bandInd[0] = find(f, 0.1, 4); // delta
        bandInd[1] = find(f, 4, 8);   // theta
        bandInd[2] = find(f, 8, 13);  // alpha
        bandInd[3] = find(f, 13, 30); // beta
    }

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to insert code

Comment: Where did you define `bandMeans`?

Comment: I edited the post according your comments - please approve

Answer (score 2):

I've followed React Native docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#callbacks to create Android native module.

> To expose a method to JavaScript a Java method must be annotated using @ReactMethod. The return type of bridge methods is always void. React Native bridge is asynchronous, so the only way to pass a result to JavaScript is by using callbacks or emitting events

```
public class TestBridge extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    public TestBridge(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "TestBridge";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getString(Callback stringCallback) {
        stringCallback.invoke("Native module String");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TestBridgePackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new TestBridge(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

insert my package in MainApplication

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    ...

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new TestBridgePackage()
      );
    }

    ...
  };

  ...
}
```

And then get a string on React Native side with callback

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  componentWillMount() {
    const TestBridge = NativeModules.TestBridge;
    TestBridge.getString(string => console.log(string));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this doesn't solve my problem. I've working react native app that I want to modify. There is a value from above (measureConcentration) in .java file (which is bridged) that I want to assign as string and display in app.

Comment: @Greynairod so you need do the same as I've done for  
`@ReactMethod`
    public void getString(Callback stringCallback) {
        stringCallback.invoke("Native module String");
    }

Comment: It would be easier guide you if you post native module code somewhere

Comment: By implementing what I asked I wanted to check particular eeg waves to find a certain pattern of sleep stages. But I think that there is to much hasse with that and easier way would be to write a .csv file with those waves.
There is github repository with this module - https://github.com/NeuroTechX/eeg-101/blob/master/EEG101/android/app/src/main/java/com/eeg_project/components/classifier/ClassifierModule.java
At the ond of this file there is code thar represents four different waves. How to write csv based on those values?

Comment: In this repository there is also https://github.com/NeuroTechX/eeg-101/blob/master/EEG101/android/app/src/main/java/com/eeg_project/components/csv/EEGFileWriter.java that might be helpful. Could you please help me to modify it to write this csv file?

Comment: @Greynairod and what value do you want to export from https://github.com/NeuroTechX/eeg-101/blob/master/EEG101/android/app/src/main/java/com/eeg_project/components/classifier/ClassifierModule.java ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
import android.util.Log;
```

and then using

```
Log.d("first string goes here", "second string goes here");
```